# AmazonWebservices Soap issue

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services

I am looking at the [AWS Documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01/DG/ItemLookup.html) There is a request element called **tagpage**,

but in the [xml for the service](http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/AWSECommerceService.wsdl)  there is no such element. Can someone help me find the element/what I am doing wrong? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would say API documentation is outdated:

http://aws.amazon.com/archives/Product%20Advertising%20API
 - says "Last Modified: Jul 26, 2011 2:10 AM GMT"

this is CURRENT version of AWSECommerceService - it's from 2011-08-01 - and it does not have tagpage element:
 http://ecs.amazonaws.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01/AWSECommerceService.wsdl

and here is OLDER version of AWSECommerceService - it's from 2011-04-01 - and it does have tagpage element:
 http://ecs.amazonaws.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-04-01/AWSECommerceService.wsdl

Comment: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01/DG/ItemLookup.html

the api indicates that the tagpage does exist, if the date in the url/api is accurate it should exist now. Has anyone come up against this problem yet?

Comment: that's what i'm saying - looks like documentation is OLD - new version of webservice does not have that field (it used to have it in the past) but documentation hasn't been updated yet.